# parsing a string in python for #hashtag

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2, hashtag

I am wondering, how could I make an algorithm that parses a string for the hashtag symbol ' # ' and returns the full string, but where ever a word starts with a '#' symbol, it becomes a link. I am using python with Google app engine: webapp2 and Jinja2 and I am building a blog.
Thanks

Comment: I find it highly troubling that people call that a "hashtag" now... :(

Comment: put your code what ever you have done here

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient and complete way to find the "hashwords":

```
import functools

def hash_position(string):
    return string.find('#')

def delimiter_position(string, delimiters):
    positions = filter(lambda x: x >= 0, map(lambda delimiter: string.find(delimiter), delimiters))
    try:
        return functools.reduce(min, positions)
    except TypeError:
        return -1

def get_hashed_words(string, delimiters):
    maximum_length = len(string)
    current_hash_position = hash_position(string)
    string = string[current_hash_position:]
    results = []
    counter = 0
    while current_hash_position != -1:
        current_delimiter_position = delimiter_position(string, delimiters)
        if current_delimiter_position == -1:
            results.append(string)
        else:
            results.append(string[0:current_delimiter_position])
        # Update offsets and the haystack
        string = string[current_delimiter_position:]
        current_hash_position = hash_position(string)
        string = string[current_hash_position:]
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = "Please #clarify: What do you #mean with returning somthing as a #link. #herp"
    delimiters = [' ', '.', ',', ':']
    print(get_hashed_words(string, delimiters))
```

Imperative code with updates of the haystack looks a little bit ugly but hey, that's what we get for (ab-)using mutable variables.

And I still have no idea what do you mean with "returning something as a link".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I meant by a link, is a clickable word. An <a> tag in html.

Comment: @user3205040, oh my G-d, really? A link pointing **where**? You know that you can't arbitarily link to things in HTML? It's really difficult to understand your question.

Comment: @user3205040 read another comment of yours. Please update your question with this information, that's the basics of Stackexchange culture. Anyway, just use my get_hashed_words function, then make the list it returns to be unique (not containing double elements), then query the database of existing hashwords adding the new hashword if needed, then add information about the article in question to denote that this article contains those hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

not sure where do you get the data for the link, but maybe something like:

```
[('<a href="...">%s</a>' % word) for word in input.split() if word[0]=='#']
```

Comment: if its the first time that the hashtag has been used then it would make a new link called www.blogname.com/thehashtagthatwasused where where all the the same hashtags can be found. Thanks alot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about twitter? Maybe this?

```
def get_hashtag_link(hashtag):
    if hashtag.startswith("#"):
        return '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%s">%s</a>' % (hashtag[1:], hashtag)

>>> get_hashtag_link("#stackoverflow")
'<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=stackoverflow">#stackoverflow</a>'
```

It will return `None` if `hashtag` is not a hashtag.